# Insert a row in a specific cell using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Is there a way to start inserting rows from a specific cell using pandas? I attach an example for better understanding, The red mark is where I want to insert the row:

```
header      header      header    header      header      header  

DATA        DATA        xxxxxx    empty       empty       empty
DATA        DATA        xxxxxx    empty       empty       empty
DATA        DATA        xxxxxx    empty       empty       empty
DATA        DATA        xxxxxx    empty       empty       empty
DATA        DATA        xxxxxx    empty       empty       empty
DATA        DATA        xxxxxx    empty       empty       empty
```

What I need is basically to open an existing csv with the structure of the example and enter the missing rows in the positions where the "xxxxxx" are.

It is important to mention that I need to enter a list in the entire row, therefore the empty values ​​should be filled with the content of the list, including and from "xxxxxx"

Maybe there is a more efficient way to do the csv, but the way I am working the information this is the most comfortable.

Comment: Not knowing enough about the structure have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html
In many cases you have a key/index in one row which you want to use for the assignment here the `on="column-name"` comes in handy.
the `how="left"` makes sense to keep all initial columns after the merge

Comment: Hey, could you provide a sample of the data? Maybe also some code that you tried and was not giving the results that you expected. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ArthurHarduim i would like to upload the example, but stack overflow says that i need 10 of reputation to post images :(

Comment: @Bobafett11, just post a portion of the text on the quest itself.

Comment: @ArthurHarduim https://ibb.co/4VY617j Here is the csv example, I need to enter rows from the yellow cell down. and the data that I want to enter is in lists

Comment: @Bobafett11 don't post images. post text. you can't expect us to re-type everything out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going off the example table above, starting with a csv without the column of 'x's.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
new_col = ['xxxx']*len(df)
df['header_insert'] = new_col
```

This will insert a new column in the right most position. If you want the columns in a specific order you'll just create a new dataframe that references the existing column headers.

For example

```py
list(df.columns)
#['header', 'header.1', 'header.2', 'header.3', 'header.4', 'header_insert']
```

To reorder

```py
new_df = df[['header', 'header.1', 'header_insert', 'header.2', 'header.3', 'header.4']]
```